# SubQuery returns one row when getting data from main query comma separated ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT 
    e.*,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(topic_name) 
        FROM topic 
        WHERE id IN (e.topic_ids)) AS topics 
FROM exam e
```

**result :**

`topics = xyz topic`

this query returns a single name of topic as result but when i use this :

```
SELECT 
    e.*,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(topic_name) 
        FROM topic 
        WHERE id IN (1,4)) AS topics 
FROM exam e
```

**result :**

`topics = xyz topic,abc topic`

That works fine,and exam table had the same value in DB (comma separated topic ids = 1,4) as varchar type field.
is there any issue with datatype of field?

Comment: Yes it's not compatible with an in test. A comma separated column is a string but and in is a set of values. So a db string of '1,4' cannot be successfully tested with in(1,4) but can be successfully tested with in('1,4') ie an exact match. In(1) will not find anything where the stored string is '1,4'

Comment: Its better to normalize your structure

Comment: Fix your data structure.  That should be where your effort goes.  Storing lists in delimited strings is not the SQLish way.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me lecture you about how bad CSV in field is.

```
| id | topic_ids |
|----|-----------|
|  1 |     a,b,c |
|  2 |       a,b |
```

This, is how Satan look like in relational DB. Probably the worst, just after the

> *"lets put columns as line and use a recursive join to get everything back."*

How it should be ?

```
exam
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |

exam_topic
| exam_id | topic_id |
|---------|----------|
|       1 |        a |
|       1 |        b |
|       1 |        c |
|       2 |        a |
|       2 |        b |

topic
| id |
|----|
|  a |
|  b |
|  c |
```

---

Now, as awful as it may be, this is the "dynamic" alternative, using [**`FIND_IN_SET()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) :

```
SELECT 
e.*,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(topic_name) 
    FROM topic 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, e.topic_ids) > 0
) AS topics 
FROM exam e
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b454b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE exam
    (`id` int, `topic_ids` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO exam
    (`id`, `topic_ids`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a,b,c'),
    (2, 'a,b'),
    (3, 'b,c,d'),
    (4, 'd')
;


CREATE TABLE topic
    (`id` varchar(1), `topic_name` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO topic
    (`id`, `topic_name`)
VALUES
    ('a', 'topA'),
    ('b', 'topB'),
    ('c', 'topC'),
    ('d', 'topD')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT 
    e.*,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(topic_name) 
        FROM topic 
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, e.topic_ids) > 0
    ) AS topics 
    FROM exam e
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b454b/1/0)**:

```
| id | topic_ids |         topics |
|----|-----------|----------------|
|  1 |     a,b,c | topA,topB,topC |
|  2 |       a,b |      topA,topB |
|  3 |     b,c,d | topB,topC,topD |
|  4 |         d |           topD |
```

Comment: Horrible, isn't it?

Comment: @Strawberry yes, and a real perf killer :/   What people don't get in "**RELATIONAL** Database" ?